In which town of Europe (Germany ?) were this 2 photos taken during WWII?
These two photographs have been in my family for many years.
I am almost sure they were taken during WWII, most probably in Germany. I have no idea by whom.

No information at the back of the photographs, but the "Kodak" name.
On the first photograph, the only detail I can extract is the name of a trademark "Kama" on the tramway carriage on the right.
The second photograph is taken in the aftermath of a bombing with a fireman at the background.
My question : can somebody identify the city, mainly on the aspect of the official building in the first photograph (hospital, town hall... ?)
Thanks for any hint.

@Giter: good find - that's the Rhône–Rhine Canal that ran between the main railway station and the downtown of Mulhouse.

The upper picture was taken in Mulhouse, France. Camera position is in front of the main railway station (nowadays Mulhouse-Ville), looking north.
The big building with a tower was the main post office, built ca. 1895 and destroyed in 1944. In 1895, Mulhouse was part of the German empire, Imperial Territory of Alsace–Lorraine. See, for example, https://www.mulhouse.fr/evenements/quartier-gare-250-ans-de-renouvellement/ (scroll down to "L’ancienne poste (1895) et la nouvelle (reconstruite après la destruction de la première durant la guerre)"). An image search for "Mülhausen Hauptpost Elsass" yields numerous picture postcards of that place. For example:

Here's a pic of the heavily damaged old post office building before it was tore down:

During the Second World War, Mulhouse was occupied by Germany (not "annexed" in a technical sense, see WP on Chief of Civil Administration).
The second pic may show the destroyed Hôtel Central in the Rue de Sauvage. Please compare the following pic:

At the left, behind the pedestrians, there's a corner building visible with a big window in the second floor and a small, rectangular window below in the ground floor (red marker on second pic):

See also the following pic of Rue de Sauvage, showing a small tower in the background, which seems to be barely visible on the second pic (green marker):

Also the ground floor facade details (blue marker) resemble the "Hôtel Central".

The second picture might show a car of the Mulhouse tram operating on line 3, as seen in this picture. There seem to be several similarities, and line 3 did traverse the downtown area.

Contemporary reporting in the Army and Navy Journal indicates Allied air attacks on railway yards in Mulhouse on May 12, 1944 and May 26, 1944.

@njuffa: Thanks a lot for that hint! Based on your work, i've emended my answer, trying to pinpoint the second pic more precisely.

An eyewitness to the first bombing of the railway facilities in Mulhouse (which they date to May 11, 1944), reports seeing an overturned tram at an intersection. The picture that follows seems to be very similar to the second picture shown here, and identifies the location as Rue du Sauvage, on the way to the train station.

The Hôtel Central in Rue du Sauvage had been established by Edouard Graeub in 1881 and claimed to be the best hotel in town.

@njuffa: I think your contruibution is worth an own answer - i woudn't have been able to identify the place of the second pic without your work. BTW: the pic from the book "Geschichten, die niemand mehr hören will" seems to be identical, guessing by the position of the people in left part of the pic.

The crucial work of identifying both the city and the specific street is all yours, so please enjoy the upvotes. I had only gotten as far as the French city of Lille in trying to identify the city, after excluding various German cities. I am happy I could corroborate your findings. If you find any of the additional information I identified helpful, feel free to incorporate it into your answer.

@tohuwawohu Cudos ! I am amazed at your findings and your so well detailed answer. How have you had the idea to look for Mulhouse ? Now, I understand more (my parents having connections with Alsace) why these photographs were in our family. I remember a joke about the fact that "rue du Sauvage" (meaning : Wildman street) was renamed "Adolf Hitler Strasse" in 1940.

@JeanMarieBecker: You're welcome! To identify the first pic, I've simply accepted the help of Google Lens :), cropping the combined pics to the first one. On a page found by user njuffa, i've found the third picture in my answer which was the key to identify the place of the second pic.

Than you for sharing yourmethodology. Thank you also to @njuffa for his/her findings.
